# GlMapBuffer takes longer and longer

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I have a problem with glMapBuffer. I'm making a simple program and I wanted to implement Sprite rendering. Since doing 500 draw calls for 500 sprites is really slow, I wanted to use one big VBO and update it every frame with new data. Good thing is, that it is faster. Weird thing is, that it slowes down as program is running.

I profiled it and the source of the problem is that calling glMapbuffer takes longer and longer. At first it uses few percents of one tick of the program, but after like a minute its already 36%. The profiler(VS community) just points me to nvoglv32.DLL, but that's dead end to me.

I seriously have no idea how to fix it.

Here is code of Sprite renderer:
http://pastebin.com/43Yp0y0M (when I copied it here, it looked really weird)
and header file: http://pastebin.com/fc0gvAUb

The are other things, but you can ignore them, they don't look like they cause the problem.

I initialize it, then in the main loop I basicly do:

```
renderer.Begin();

for(data)
   renderer.Submit(data.pos,data.dims,data.col);

renderer.End();

renderer.Render();
```

Is this correct way to implement something like this? I mean, maybe I'm forgetting some important glCall somewhere.

I let it run for 15minutes, now just mapping the buffer takes 20ms: ( I also updated my drivers, but even that did not help.

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/debug_5) I uploaded the executable, maybe it is just my computer, which doesnt solve the problem but its something. Well, there is a good chance that it wont work, because I have no experience with distributing .exe    . For anyone interested, you can move with arrow keys :) Also, it has console, first column is FPS, second is Update timer and the third is actual SpriteRenderer time, which is increasing atleast for me :(

Comment: Are you repeatedly calling `glMapBuffer` without calling `glUnmapBuffer`?

Comment: @RedRoboHood Yes, I unmap it in End function asi is shown in source code. I also added Error checking and nothing outputs an error :(

Answer (score 1):

Oh, stupid me, trying to blame OpenGL.

The mistake was in num_sprites variable, which didnt reset, so it  increased every frame. Then it was used in glDrawElements, so what I think that Opengl did was realoccating the buffer and making it bigger instead of allowing access to not allocated memory. The bigger the buffer got the longer took to map it.

This was quite hard to find for me, because the actual mistake was elsewhere.
So, this is my story of first bigger bug discovery, wonder how many are there still hidden :D